# Trouble loading/showing Flexslider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm trying to use Flexslider and I'm having trouble wrapping the Flexslider in another div, hiding it, then attempting to show that whole div when a button is clicked. I'm not using an AJAX call to load the slider or any of my other divs, but instead (since the site is relatively simple and small) using JQ to hide and then show things when buttons are clicked.

```
**//This is the JQuery I've tried using**
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('#projectsPage').hide();
$('#projectsLink').click(function(){
$('#projectsPage').fadeIn(1000).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    slideshow: true,
    animationLoop: true,
    animationSpeed: "3000",
    slideshowSpeed: "8000",
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: false
  });
});
});
</script>

**<!-- HTML-->**

<!--Click this link to show the div containing the flexslider-->
<a href="#projectsPage" id="projectsLink">link</a>

<!--Div containing the flexslider div (which is part of the source code)-->
<div id="projectsPage">
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="js/flexslider/images/img2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="js/flexslider/images/img3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
     <img src="js/flexslider/images/img4.jpg" />
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

This code is part of a grander document, but it's not all that complicated. Can someone tell me if I'm breaking something or need to include more information?

Also, there appears to be no error in the JS Console so I'm pretty stumped as to why it won't show. It "loads" the #projectsPage div, as indicated in the URL, but then shows nothing in the window.

I'm pretty new to JQuery so be nice :)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think .load is the funciton you are looking for.

Comment: If you want an fadeIn effect, you might have to apply some styles before the fadeIn to get it to be the correct size, then initialize the flexslider, and then call the fadeIn, otherwise the size of a hidden container is usually 0px, which causes the flexslider to remain hidden even after you fade it in.

Comment: A better approach would likely be to initialize the flexslider at load time, then hide it.  On click, fadeIn might work for you without too much trouble, otherwise you'll need to get the flexslider to resize itself (there is likely a flexslider resize method you can call).  Otherwise you'll be reinitializing the flexslider if you allow the user to then hide it and reshow it again.

Answer (score 1):

the slider can't initialize inside of a hidden div.

I had this same issue hiding multiple flexsliders in divs that only displayed when their thumbnail was clicked. To make this work, set up a jquery click() listener on the element that will cause the slider to show, and initialize the slider after the containing div is un-hidden.

Something like the following:

```
$('.show_slider_link_class').click( function(){

    //show containing element
    $('.hidden_slider_container').show();

            // now you can init the flexslider
    $('.flexslider_').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: "thumbnails",
        minItems: 1,
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
});
```